# Something is not working in my code javascript to make a triangle

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I made this code but it displays a line with spaces, I need to make a triangle with "*"

can someone help me telling me whats wrong?

```
function makeTriangle(){
  let row, star;
  let toPrint = "";
  let rowCount =+prompt("enter number");

  for (row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++) {
    for (star = 1; star <= row; star++){
      toPrint += "*";
    }
    toPrint +="\n\n";
  }
  document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = toPrint
}
```

Comment: You should include some HTML (what it looks like before and after this function runs) to help people see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is using `"\n\n"` to add the line break. But to add line break, you have to use `<br>`. The reason is that, when the `innerHTML` is set to `toPrint`, the DOM shows stars in an indented form because of `"\n\n"`. But when that HTML is rendered and displayed on the webpage, no line break is there. Therefore, you need to use HTML entity `<br>` to add line break.

```js
function makeTriangle() {
  let toPrint = "";
  let rowCount = +prompt("enter number");

  for (let row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++) {
    for (let star = 1; star <= row; star++)
      toPrint += "*";

    toPrint += "<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = toPrint
}

makeTriangle();
```

```css
#outputNumber {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="outputNumber"></div>
```